# Vowpal Wabbit: Low-rank matrix factorization?

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit, matrix-factorization

I have a very basic question. I'd like to do low-rank matrix factorization and I was looking at the [Vowpal Wabbit documentation](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments) on the topic. My question is:

**Is there a difference between these two approaches?** (implementation or otherwise)

```
$ vw --lrq ab5
```

or

```
$ vw -q ab --rank 5
```

Here, `a` and `b` are feature namespaces and `5` is the latent-factor dimensionality.

---

Possible follow-up:

**If these are equivalent, will `--rank` also work for higher-order interactions?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Short answer:

`--rank` and `--lrq` are two separate and very different, implementations of matrix factorization/decomposition in vowpal wabbit.

"Matrix factorization", sometimes referred to as "Matrix decomposition" is a general term in ML, there are many ways to approximate a matrix using simpler factors (sometimes with loss of info).

Although they bear some similarities in that they both try to capture the strongest latent interactions between two feature subsets, they are not equivalent neither in implementation nor in the quality of the model they produce.  Their performance strongly depends on the problem at hand.

#### In more detail:

- `--rank` was the first implementation of MF in `vw` by Jake Hofman. It was inspired by [SVD (Singular Value Decomposition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)
- `--lrq` was implemented a few years later by Paul Mineiro. It was inspired by [libfm](http://www.libfm.org/)

On data-sets which are hard to generalize from (e.g. movielens 1M where user has at most one rating per movie), `--lrq` seems to perform better. It seems to be using better defaults, converges faster, is more efficient and generates much smaller on-disk models.  `--rank` may perform better on other data-sets where there's more examples per user/item to generalize from.

You can tell the two implementation produce different results by running an example. e.g. pick a dataset under the `test` directory and run the two algos on it:

```
vw --lrq aa3       test/train-sets/0080.dat
```

versus:

```
vw --rank 3 -q aa  test/train-sets/0080.dat
```

Feel free to add: `--holdout_off -c --passes 1000` to make them run longer so you can compare run-times between the two.

You would note that the two use a different number of features per example (`--lrq` is more minimalistic and will only look at the subset you explicitly tell it to), that the convergence, and final average loss is better with `--lrq`.  If you store the model with `-f modelname` - you'd note it'll be much smaller with `--lrq` especially on big data-sets.

OTOH, if you try a data-set like `test/train-sets/ml100k_small_train` in the source tree, with a rank of 10 between the namespaces `u` (user) and `i` (item), you would get a better loss with `--rank` than with `--lrq`. This shows that which one is better depends on the data-set at hand.

#### Higher-exponent interactions (e.g. `--cubic`)

To your second question: `--rank` will not allow higher interactions. If you try to add `--cubic` you'll get an error:

```
vw (gd_mf.cc:139): cannot use triples in matrix factorization
```

but it will allow multiple/additional `-q` (quadratic) interactions.

`--lrq` is less fussy, so you may add higher-order interaction options to it.

#### More differences:

Generally, `--lrq` is more agnostic and independent of other `vw` options while `--rank` is using its own standalone [SGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) code and doesn't accept other options (like `--normalized`, or `--adaptive`).  Also, memory requirements for `--rank` are higher.

Again, results will depend on the data, additional options, and specific interactions.

#### Further reading

#### --rank

- [`--rank` example in the wiki](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Matrix-factorization-example)
- [SVD on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)

#### --lrq

- [`--lrq` demo in the source tree](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/tree/master/demo/movielens)
- [`libfm` (by Steffen Rendle) after which `--lrq` was designed](http://www.libfm.org/) with many further references.

Comment: finally, one of the vw guys cares to share an answer on this :-)

Comment: well, so `lrq` optimizes an objective function which should be similar with fm, whereas `rank` optimizes a different one?

Comment: Yes, I believe `--rank N` does an iterative approximation of  [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) where only the top N diagonal terms are computed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @arielf, much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @Kris and @avocado. The main reason I noticed this old Q was that it appeared in the 'Related' column with 0 answers when I answered a new related Q.  I usually try to answer Qs with the vowpal-wabbit tag, when I feel I know the answer, which is not always the case.  Over the years, `vw` has grown to cover many algorithms I don't know enough about to help.  Looking at the source code can help, and adding the `--audit` option on small data can be a great clarifier.